# SQL XML column - update child node value based on other nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlxml

I am not used to use xml in an sql column and have a question about updating the content of that column.

I have a table (`TableXML`) with a column (`ColumnXML`) containing the following xml hierarchy : `Xml/Content/Queues/list/Item/`

Each Item have a `/Name`, a list of `PluginsProperties/Item`

and each of these other item have a `/key` and `value`

For example :

```
<Xml>
    <Content Tr="1">
        <Queues Tr="12">
            <list Tr="13">
                <Item Tr="14">
                    <Name Tr="2">Data Load Exception</Name>
                    <PluginProperties Tr="15">
                        <Item Tr="16">
                            <key Tr="2">MSMQQueueType</key>
                            <value Tr="2">PrivateQueue</value>
                        </Item>
                        ...........more items
                    </PluginProperties>
                </Item>
                ...........more items
            </list>
        </Queues>
    </Content>
</Xml>
```

What I would like to do :

Update the value of the `/Xml/Content/Queues/list/Item/PluginProperties/Item/value` tag to `PublicQueue`

where the `/Xml/Content/Queues/list/Item/PluginProperties/Item/key` is `MSMQQueueType`

and the `/Xml/Content/Queues/list/Item/Name` is `Data Load Exception`

No "Queue item" other than the one with name `Data Load Exception` should be affected and no "PluginProperties item" other than the one with key `MSMQQueueType` should be affected for it.

Thanks! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `replace value of` clause to do this

if it was a single node then it can be done in with single statement like below

```
     update TableXML
     set columnXML.modify('
            replace value of    ((/Xml/Content/Queues/list/Item/PluginProperties/Item/value)[1]/text())[1] with ''PublicQueue''')
 where columnXML.value('((/Xml/Content/Queues/list/Item/PluginProperties/Item/key)[1]/text())[1]','varchar(50)') = 'MSMQQueueType' 
  and columnXML.value('((/Xml/Content/Queues/list/Item/Name)[1]/text())[1]','varchar(50)') = 'Data Load Exception'
```

AS there exists many nodes, we need to get the count of the nodes and do it using while loop like below

```
declare @elements int

select @elements = ISNULL(columnXML.value('count(/Xml/Content/Queues/list/Item/PluginProperties/Item)', 'int'),0)
from TableXML


while @elements > 0 
begin

  update TableXML
  set columnXML.modify
    ('replace value of ((/Xml/Content/Queues/list/Item/PluginProperties/Item/value)[sql:variable("@elements")]/text())[1]
      with ''PublicQueue''')
  where columnXML.value('((/Xml/Content/Queues/list/Item/PluginProperties/Item/key)[sql:variable("@elements")]/text())[1]','varchar(50)') = 'MSMQQueueType' 
  and columnXML.value('((/Xml/Content/Queues/list/Item/Name)[sql:variable("@elements")]/text())[1]','varchar(50)') = 'Data Load Exception' 


  set @elements = @elements - 1
end
```

Comment: Hi and thanks! Is there no way with SQL XML to update many nodes with a single statement? (all nodes matching the filter)

Comment: @ibiza, i don't think there is a mass update option for all XML nodes